# pip: Could not find an activated virtualenv (required)

Tags: python, osx-mountain-lion, virtualenv, pip

I am trying to instal virtualenv and/or virtualenvwrapper on a Mac OS X 10.8.3.

I have been fighting with python for the last two days. Finally I was able to install Python 2.7.4 using brew.  Before I had `virtualenv` installed using `easy_install`. Then I tried to uninstall it, trying to get my computer in the same situation as the one of my colleagues. Maybe I uninstalled it with success, maybe not. I don't know how to test it. Now I am supposed to install virtualenv using:

```
pip install virtualenv
```

But it gives me:

```
Could not find an activated virtualenv (required).
```

`pip install virtualenvwrapper` gives exactly the same output.

Also the variable: `PIP_RESPECT_VIRTUALENV` is null:

```
echo $PIP_RESPECT_VIRTUALENV
```

How can I solve this issue?

Answer (score 116, accepted):

Open your `~/.bashrc` file and see if this line is there -

```
export PIP_REQUIRE_VIRTUALENV=true
```

It might be causing the trouble. If it's there, change it to `false` and run -

```
source ~/.bashrc
```

If not, run `export PIP_REQUIRE_VIRTUALENV=false` from terminal.

Note: everything works the same if you have `.bash_profile` instead of `.bashrc` in your current user's root directory.

Comment: For anyone else coming across this: Please note the difference between `PIP_RESPECT_VIRTUALENV` (as mentioned in the original question) and `PIP_REQUIRE_VIRTUALENV`, which is the solution mentioned above.

Comment: Trouble leading to this error could also be called by other settings in `.bashrc`, such as `VIRTUALENVWRAPPER_PYTHON`. Running `export PIP_REQUIRE_VIRTUALENV=false` and then a pip uninstall / install virtualenv worked in my case.

Answer (score 10):

@Bibhas has it; +1 to look for `export PIP_REQUIRE_VIRTUALENV=true` in `~/.profile` or `~/.bashrc`. You can confirm the setting in your current shell with `env |grep PIP_REQUIRE_VIRTUALENV`.

This setting is a good safety check; more often than not, you'll want to be installing things into virtualenvs. However, sometimes you *do* want to be working with the global/system python. In those cases, take a look at [--isolated](https://pip.pypa.io/en/latest/reference/pip.html#cmdoption--isolated):

> Run pip in an isolated mode, ignoring environment variables and user configuration.

```
$ pip install --upgrade pip
Could not find an activated virtualenv (required).
$ pip install --upgrade pip --isolated
Requirement already up-to-date: pip in /usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages
$ pip freeze --isolated
...
```

Comment: See also the other answer about `~/.pip/pip.conf`. The environment will override the pip.conf setting, but maybe it's better to change it at the source if you need to change the behavior.

Answer (score 6):

An additional solution to those already presented is to add a shell command that will allow you to install py packages by temporarily overriding the default setting.  Add this to your `~/.profile`, `~/.bashrc` or wherever you maintain your shell's exports/settings (in my case, `~/.zshrc`).

```
syspip(){
    PIP_REQUIRE_VIRTUALENV="" pip "$@"
}
```

With this simple addition, you can install pip packages to the system via `syspip install <package>`.

Answer (score 4):

Verify contents of ~/.pip/pip.conf like:

```
[global]
index=https://pypi.python.org/simple/

require-virtualenv=false
```

if previous it was set like require-virtualenv=true

Answer (score 2):

Important to heed @JCotton's advice here-- keeping your pip setup so as to only install into virtualenvs is a great practice.

His solution to get virtualenv setup again of `pip install --upgrade pip --isolated` is exactly what should be done.

You should NOT turn off requiring a virtualenv, either by config file or by editing ~/.bash_rc or ~/.bash_profile, to get your project's pip packages installed. We're only doing it here because OP needs virtualenv itself installed.

In general, *I see people get this message when their virtualenv wasn't setup correctly for their project in the first place*. Reminder that to create a virtualenv with its own python and pip so that you don't run into the "could not find an activated virtualenv" error, you run `virtualenv -p python3`

Comment: Would appreciate a canonical link to the mentioned advice. I generally agree with virtualenv being a good idea for writing applications. There are times when one is not writing a "project"*. It's a one-liner, say, or some small, throwaway test cases. Virtualenv is just annoying and impedes in these cases, particularly when things like pyyaml are not there by default. But, maybe I'm doing it wrong? Always looking to upgrade my knowledge.

Answer (score 1):

Another place where you may possibly have this "lock" is the `pip.conf` file. In my case I had one in my `~/Library/Application Support/pip` folder and forgot  about it.

Typical content of the file could be:

```
[install]
require-virtualenv = true

[uninstall]
require-virtualenv = true
```

Similar to other answers, `false` should be changed to `true` in the file.

Comment: also this file could be found at `~/.pip/pip.conf`

Answer (score -1):

for matchbook you must go to '.bash_profile '

1) open with your favorite editor in terminal

nano .bash_profile OR vim .bash_profile

2) find the text line that says

export PIP_REQUIRE_VIRTUALENV=true

3) delete it or set it equal to "false"

4) finally restart your terminal

Comment: How this is different from the currently accepted solution?

Comment: Well it’s on a different file that’s why I post it. Because with the guide here I could not find it