# Can system pip install modules into a venv created --without-pip?

Tags: python, pip, virtualenv

Using python 3.4.3 with pip 8.1.2 on Cygwin / Windows 7.

I want to maintain one updated system-wide pip rather than having to install and upgrade it for every new venv.

The bundled pip is otherwise quite out of date:

```
$ python3 -c 'import ensurepip; print(ensurepip.version())'
6.0.8
```

I don't want to maintain any system-wide modules other than pip, rather all dependencies should land in the venv.

I've tried:

```
$ pyvenv-3.4 --without-pip venv
$ source venv/bin/activate
(venv) $ which pip python
/usr/bin/pip
$HOME/venv/bin/python
```

Which is what I expect.
But then:

```
(venv) $ export PIP_REQUIRE_VIRTUALENV=true
(venv) $ pip show pip
Could not find an activated virtualenv (required).
```

Which is quite confounding.

```
(venv) $ PIP_REQUIRE_VIRTUALENV= pip show pip
---
Metadata-Version: 2.0
Name: pip
Version: 8.1.2
[...]
```

If I disable PIP_REQUIRE_VIRTUALENV and run pip install MODULE, pip will run,
but the MODULE gets installed in my system site-packages, not under venv.

I did figure a workaround by using --system-site-packages:

```
$ pyvenv-3.4 --without-pip --system-site-packages venv
$ source venv/bin/activate
(venv) $ export PIP_REQUIRE_VIRTUALENV=true
(venv) $ python -c 'import pip; pip.main()' show pip
---
Metadata-Version: 2.0
Name: pip
Version: 8.1.2
```

I would rather not take the chance of requirements leaking in from system-wide modules. Is there an easier way? Am I wrong to expect the system pip to 'respect my venv'?

There's a similar [question here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16460313/pip-could-not-find-an-activated-virtualenv-required) regarding use of PIP_RESPECT_VIRTUALENV and/or --respect-virtualenv but, I find nothing relevant in the current pip sources.

Answer (score 0):

I also didn't want to install updated version of `pip` to `venv`, so used `--without-pip`. But initially I wanted to reuse some binary modules from the system so I created venv as:

```
# mkdir ~/.venv

# pip index versions ansible
ansible (7.3.0)

# python3 -m venv --without-pip --system-site-packages ansible-7.3.0
```

`pip` is not in `~/.venv/.../bin`, system `pip` tells cannot install to system dir so install to user dir (`~/.local/share/`).

There is a way to use venv `pip` by running it as module inside venv (which is available because of `--system-site-packages`):

```
python -m pip install --require-virtualenv ansible==7.3.0
```