# Brew install pip3, cannot install virtualenv

Tags: python, macos, homebrew

I've followed this tutorial on setting up a python dev environment on osx high-sierra, but for the life of me I cannot get pip3 to install virtualenv

```
$ pip3 install virtualenv
$ Could not find an activated virtualenv (required).
```

my .bash_profile contains export PATH=/usr/local/bin:/usr/local/sbin:$PATH
as the last line.

```
$ python --version
$ Python 2.7.10
```

&

```
$ python --version
$ Python 3.6.5
```

This doesn't help me either: [pip: Could not find an activated virtualenv (required)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16460313/pip-could-not-find-an-activated-virtualenv-required)

I'm stumped. Suggestions sought and welcome.

Comment: Try: pip3 install --upgrade pip3

Comment: wrogrammer - That gives me the same error. "Could not find an activated virtualenv (required)."

Comment: I moved on to a different Setting up Python dev in osx guide: https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-install-python-3-and-set-up-a-local-programming-environment-on-macos if anyone comes across this post.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

python3 has incorporated virtualenv into the venv module rendering the module [unnecessary](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23842713/using-python-3-in-virtualenv).

Comment: So it is. Thanks.

Comment: Glad to help, mate.