# I installed SpaCy with Anaconda but how do I add the models

Tags: python, anaconda, models, spacy

I use Spyder with Anaconda. SpaCy is a standard module and installs just fine. But there is no standard way to add the models.
Simply putting them in the spacy/data directory as is suggested on some sites does not work.
It results in the following error:

> FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/Users/username/anaconda/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/spacy/data/en_core_web_sm/en_core_web_sm-2.1.0a0/parser/tok2vec_model'

Comment: `python -m spacy download en_core_web_sm` Have you installed the models?

Comment: I tried, but this gives an error: Could not find an activated virtualenv (required).

Comment: [Have you checked this?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16460313/pip-could-not-find-an-activated-virtualenv-required)

Comment: Thanks, it worked now.  
in terminal before:  
python -m spacy download en_core_web_sm . 
run:  
export PIP_REQUIRE_VIRTUALENV=false

Answer (score 1):

What worked for me was the now considered "standard way":

> Step 1 : Install spacy Run the below command in Anaconda Prompt (Run
> as administrator)
>
> `conda install -c conda-forge spacy`
>
> Step 2 : Install language model
>
> `python -m spacy download en # default English model (~50MB)`
>
> `python -m spacy download en_core_web_md # larger English model (~1GB)`

In my case just the default small one (50mb) was fine.

Source:
[copy-paste from here](https://rpubs.com/mohammadshadan/install_spacy)