# Conda doesn't show package installed using pip

Tags: python, anaconda, virtualenv, conda

I am following this guide here,

https://spinningup.openai.com/en/latest/user/installation.html

```
conda create -n spinningup python=3.6

source activate spinningup

git clone https://github.com/openai/spinningup.git

cd spinningup

pip install -e .
```

And I get the following error:
[image]

I have overriden that error by

```
export PIP_REQUIRE_VIRTUALENV=false
```

But the none of the installed packages are not shown in the conda package list, it appears the packages are installed on the main python environment, not conda environment?

[image: Installed dependencies not shown]

```
which pip
```

does point to correct conda pip directory however.

[image]
Pip list shows gym is installed, but when I open juptyer lab from this same terminal :

[image]

According to this [link](https://towardsdatascience.com/environment-management-with-conda-python-2-3-b9961a8a5097):

> Most of the time (with some exceptions) there isn’t much of a difference between installing packages through conda or through pip. This is because pip packages are also installable into Conda environments.

It should have been installed into conda env I have created, but why isn't this working?

How can I fix this?
I wish to install everything specified in this spinningup requirement.txt on conda env, like the guide suggested.

Many thanks in advance.

Comment: did you check this? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16460313/pip-could-not-find-an-activated-virtualenv-required .

Comment: Yes, that is the exactly why I mention "setting PIP_REQUIRE_VIRTUALENV=false" here. If I do that, it installs in the main Python environment, not Conda environment. I want these dependencies to be installed in Conda env like the guide suggested.

Comment: What version of conda are you using? `source activate` is quite old; you should be using `conda activate`.

Comment: As for the actual issue you're facing, you probably need to `conda install pip` into the active environment so that `pip` refers to that environment's pip, not the system pip.

Comment: I am using the latest version of conda. Thank you for conda activate tip. 'which pip' already points to /anaconda3/envs/spinningup/bin/pip so this isn't the issue..